# How to apply connection pooling?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, connection-pooling

I am specific about this tutorial: [The BalusC Code: DAO tutorial - use in JSP/Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html) 
How can I apply connection pooling together with this code? What will be the changes in the code?

Comment: I have tried and successfully implement my application with similar code as given in this tutorial and the tutorial before it, but when i tried to do connection pooling as given in the tutorial i cannot connect to the database. What code should I post here to get u know what i am doing?

Comment: exception - `BasicDataSource not supported`, while calling `daoFactory.getConnection()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Tomcat, but at least Application Servers such as GlassFish come with connection pool functionality integrated. You just need to configure the connection details in the admin interface. Then in your EJB use:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

The container will take care of the connection pooling.

Comment: see this link http://balusc.blogspot.in/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html#HowAboutConnectionPooling, but i am unable to configure it for my use..